# Создание поста сперва на основном языке

Tags: wordpress, wpml

При создании поста проверять есть ли пост на основном языке. Если пост есть на основном языке то создавать пост, если нету такого поста то отобразить уведомление "создайте пост сперва на основном языке". Исполюзую плагин WPML

Comment: Обычно когда на основном языке есть пост, Вы же как бы добавляете его перевод, скажем так, а не создаете новый и не связанный с основным пост.

Comment: Проблема в том что контентщики берут и создают на любом языке пост. А нужно чтоб сперва на основном языке сперва создавался

Comment: Окей, по какому критерию тогда Вы себе представляете такую проверку? На разных же языках будут разные заголовки, текст поста и так далее, по какому критерию проверять?

Comment: у wpml есть связка постов по trid кажется

Comment: Есть, но не совсем понимаю как это поможет если кто-то создает запись с 0 и не удосужился проверить нужно ли привязать ее к какому-то оригиналу, то есть перевод никоим образом не связан с оригиналом и это самостоятельная запись.

Comment: Добавляешь страницу, проверяешь язык, если нет этой страницы на дефолтном языке, тогда забрасываешь ее в корзину, а не публикуешь и выводишь сообщения, чтобы сначала добавили страницу на основном языке

Comment: Тогда в чем проблема?) Вы так и не объяснили каким образом происходит это самое "проверяешь", если это делается не вручную.

Comment: проблема в том что не хватает знаний) я больше по фронту, но бывают задачи и по беку

Comment: Как определишься с критериями "точного такого же, но другого" так и можно будет говорить предметно.  Но проблема не в этом, а в неумении и не желании учиться работать с инструментами. Это твои "контентщики" должны не тупо постить, а постить ***перевод***, Это немного другая работа. Однако и после тупого постинга можно связать посты на разных языках (хотя это уже крайний случай).